# Add event to a html tag element through DOM

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<input type="text" title="Search" tabindex="0" name="" aria-label="search input" role="searchbox" id="er_search_input_dummy" placeholder="Find your eBook" autocomplete="off">
```

and I want to add `onclick="this.select()"` to this iput tag but can't edit it directly. Is there a way through DOM or something to add this into `<input>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",
  (e) => document.getElementById("er_search_input_dummy")
    .addEventListener("click",(e) => e.target.select()))
```

```html
<input type="text" title="Search" tabindex="0" name="" aria-label="search input" role="searchbox" id="er_search_input_dummy" placeholder="Find your eBook" autocomplete="off">
```

If you want this.select() then you need `function() {}` instead of `(e) =>`:

```js
window.addEventListener("load",
  (e) => document.getElementById("er_search_input_dummy")
    .addEventListener("click",function() { this.select(); }))
```

```html
<input type="text" title="Search" tabindex="0" name="" aria-label="search input" role="searchbox" id="er_search_input_dummy" placeholder="Find your eBook" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Thanks it works , I tried using `document.getElementById("er_search_input_dummy")
    .addEventListener("click",document.getElementById("er_search_input_dummy").select())` but it did not work can you tell why is it so ?

Comment: That should work, but why would you type more than needed? Also if you use function() { instead of (e) => you can use this.select() instead of e.target.select()

Comment: I ue this.selct() but it did not work so I thought this is not the way